# NGINX Not Serving "Fast" Stale Content with proxy_cache_background_update

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, cache

We are running NGINX in front of our backend server.

We are attempting to enable the **proxy_cache_background_update** feature to allow NGINX to async updates to the cache and serve STALE content while it does this.

However, we are noticing that it still delivers STALE content slowly as if it's not serving from the cache.  The time it takes after an item expires is very slow and clearly not served from cache - you can tell it's going to the backend server, getting an update and delivering it to the client.

Here is our configuration from NGINX:

```
proxy_cache_revalidate on;
proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
proxy_cache_background_update   on;
```

Our backend server is delivering the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2019 21:07:09 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: max-age=1800, stale-while-revalidate=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

When attempting an expired page fetch we do notice the following header:

```
X-Cache: STALE
```

However, when providing this response it is very slow as if it's contacted the backend server and done it in realtime.

NGINX version:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.9
```

Any suggestions, tips and config changes are greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It seems that the nginx server is *honoring* serving stale content (as we have tested) but it also updates the cache from the backend on the same request/thread thus causing the slow response time to the client.  I.e. it seems to be totally ignoring the `proxy_cache_background_update   on;` directive and not updating in the background on a separate subrequest (async).

Answer (score 1):

Please go to ticket:

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1738#comment:6

Seems that this is a reopened bug.

Comment: 1738 links to https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1723 which is also fun to read

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding. `keepalive_timeout 0;` to the location block.

Comment: that improves the situation a little but it doesn't completely solve it. nginx still does *not actually* process those "background" requests in the background. it's definitely not a configuration issue but a limitation of the feature's implementation. they *could* implement a worker to fetch stale resources, and queries add to a queue of such resources to be updated. that is not the case however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `proxy_cache_use_stale updating;`

From the docs for that parameter:

> the `updating` parameter permits using a stale cached response if it is currently being updated.

And for `proxy_cache_background_update` they have this to say:

> Note that it is necessary to allow the usage of a stale cached response when it is being updated.

Which is what's `proxy_cache_use_stale updating;` is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  We have tried with `proxy_cache_use_stale updating;` however the same behavior happens.  As far as I'm aware, there is also no need to use `proxy_cache_use_stale updating;` when the backend sets a Cache Control:  stale-while-revalidate header.  The issue seems to be that it honors serving STALE content but it is also updating the cache on the same thread as the request comes in - i.e. it's simply ignoring `proxy_cache_background_update   on;`

Comment: I have updated the question above with additional details.

Comment: Hey @TedWilmont. I think I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @Lucas Pelegrino, maybe you both just had to upgrade nginx: http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/rev/9552758a786e

Comment: Thanks @DanilaVershinin, but I'm on version 1.15.9, and according to source control already has the mentioned changes: http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/file/9552758a786e/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c

Comment: I stumbled upon exactly the same issue. @LucasPelegrino , have you guys managed to solve this?

Comment: @egordoe I think we never solved this. If you do, please share :)